# I did that the form1 will move slowly to the left. How can i make that it will start from the center of the screen?

Tags: c#, winforms

At the top of Form1 i did:

```
private IntPtr ID;
private int counter = 0;
```

In the constructor i did:

```
ID = this.Handle;
timer2.Enabled = true;
```

Then in timer2 tick event i did:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (counter <= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Right)
                MoveWindow(ID, counter++, 0, this.Width, this.Height, true);
            else
                counter = 0;
        }
```

But the form start to move from the top left corner at 0,0 to the right.
I want the form will start to move from the center of the screen to the left untill it hit the left border/bound and stop and stay there.

How can i do it ?

I found now how to make it to move to the left and stop on the left border/bound:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (counter >= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Left)
                MoveWindow(ID, counter--, 0, this.Width, this.Height, true);
            else
                counter = 0;
        }
```

But how do i make that it will start to move from the middle/center of the screen ?
I did in the designer change the property: StartPosition to CenterScreen
But the form start to move from the top left corner 0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better solution for you, just use the `protected` method `CenterToScreen()` like this:

```
this.CenterToScreen();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer.

```
x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom - this.Width * 2;
y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Bottom - this.Height * 2;
counter = x;
```

Then in the timer tick event:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (counter >= Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Left)
                MoveWindow(ID, counter--, y, this.Width, this.Height, true);
            else
                counter = 0;
        }
```

Before it the counter-- was set to 0. And instead y it was 0 too.
So it's 0,0 this is the location.
Now counter and y start location is the middle of the screen.

Thanks.

Comment: I have a better solution for you, see my answer. **It's better not because of it's more efficient, it's just because it's shorter, more succinct and takes the benefit of the already built-in method**

Answer (score 0):

You could set the [`StartPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) property of your main WinForm to `CenterScreen`:

```
 Form1.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

Then if you want it to appear somehow on a different position relative to this screen center, you can play with the [`Top`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.top.aspx) and [`Left`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.left.aspx) properties to add or subtract the required number of pixels.

if you need to know the screen bounds:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
```

or, taking into account the task bar:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea
```

...or some variant